# How can i let my code make a sqlite database when it doens't exist?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make a sqlite database but I can't succeed. the big problem with this is that I don't get any error. I can't even make a .db file manually because it will not be found. I am working with Xamarin forms and I use visual studio 2015 to edit my code/files. This is my code:

ISQLite interface:

```
 ...
    public interface ISQLite
        {
            SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
        }
 ...
```

DB helper (called TheMapDB.cs):

```
... 
public class TheMapDB
    {
        private SQLiteConnection db;

        public TheMapDB()
        {
            //Getting conection and Creating table  
            db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            db.CreateTable<Categories>();
            db.CreateTable<Places>();
            db.CreateTable<Events>();
        }

        public void AddCategorie(Categories categorie)
        {
            db.Insert(categorie);
        }
    }
    ...
```

Tables (file called Tables.cs):

```
public class Categories
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Menu_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Categories()
    {
    }
}
```

android native side(called SQLite_Android.cs):

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]
namespace AmsterdamTheMapV3.Droid 
{
    public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLite_Android() { }
        public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var filename = "database.db3";
            var documentspath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentspath, filename);

            var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            var connection = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(platform, path);
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

how I call the functions:

```
    static TheMapDB database;
    Categories student = new Categories();
    TheMapDB categorie = new TheMapDB();

    public HomePage()
    {
        student.ID = 1;
        student.Menu_ID = 2;
        student.Name = "peter";
        categorie.AddCategorie(student);
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        categorie.GetCategorie(1);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I know that it is a lot of code but i have no idea where the problem is.
I can give more info if needed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace :-

```
 var documentspath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

With

```
 var documentspath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

It might be a issue of folder access .

**Edited :-**

Also before creating database, please also put a condition to check if it already created, otherwise it will replace the database.

Comment: I did change it but now i get this error: Could not copy the file "Assets\Database.db3" because it was not found. AmsterdamTheMapV3.Droid

after I added Database.db3 manually and now there is now error but also no database only that one i make manually

Comment: Instead of creating database via code, you can create it in sqlite editor in firefox and can place it in your applications folder(blank database). On application load you can check if database not exists in %appdata% folder then you can copy if from applications folder to %appdata% folder.

Comment: You can use "System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);" to copy file.

Comment: If I use firefox SQLite editor it will make a .sqlite file and not a .db3 file

Comment: You can refer this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176710/how-to-create-a-db3-database-with-sqlite-net

Comment: Thank you i think i understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

Use SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(filename.sqlite) method to create the file.

Comment: If i do that will it loop? because i only need 1 database not 10 :-)

Comment: Don't put it in loop, if there is a loop then you can place a "File.Exists()" check.